Drizzle ORM Postgres error - bind message supplies 1 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 0
Code:
export async function fetchPaymentMethod(name: string) {
        const res = await db.select().from(PaymentMethodsTable).where(sql`lower(${PaymentMethodsTable.name}) = '${name}'`);

        return res[0];
    }

Error:
bind message supplies 1 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 0
    at async fetchPaymentMethod (./app/lib/data/main.ts:36:17)

Explanation:
I'm using Drizzle ORM on a NextJS project. For some reason this part of the code seems to be creating the error: '${name}'.
But this seems to be in line with the official Drizzle ORM docs which you can read here: https://orm.drizzle.team/docs/select
I'm looking for a fix, alternative implementation, anything.

The variable should not be wrapped in quote '.
So it should be
sql`lower(${PaymentMethodsTable.name}) = ${name}`

Source: https://github.com/drizzle-team/drizzle-orm/issues/1140#issuecomment-1722587563
